# Python Type Conversion/Casting Syntax Differences

Tags: python

I'm wondering what the difference between the following two snippets of code is:

```
float_var = 1234.5678
a = int(float_var)
b = (int)(float_var)
```

They both successfully convert the variable to an integer (at least in Python 3.6, I don't know if this behaviour is supported in 2.7) but there's an obvious difference in syntax. Furthermore, the following snippet fails:

```
c = (int)float_var
```

Which leads me to believe that the variable name (or literal, as it may be) must be enclosed in parentheses.

From what I can gather the difference in the two examples is that the first one creates a new instance of a class by passing a parameter into its __init__ method. Whereas in the second example, since the int object defines a method __float__, it can "cast" any float to an instance of int.

Am I correct in thinking this? Also, why does the third example fail? I don't understand why parentheses are required to surround the value being "cast".

Comment: Also, is there any reason that the second example isn't used as widely as the first one? My guess is that it's not as clear, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `a` and `b` are identical.

Comment: It's likely the parenthesis around `int` simply do nothing. You could use the `dis` module to look at the the resultant bytecode it will be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

Python types are objects and can be called like functions. The `int(foo)` syntax may be shared by Python and C, but the similarities end there.

In your code, `int == (int) == ((int))` all are equal in the same way `1 + 1 == (1 + 1) == ((1 + 1))`. If you look at the bytecode, Python treats both identically:

```
In [42]: dis.dis(lambda: (int)(a))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (a)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE

In [43]: dis.dis(lambda: int(a))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (int)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (a)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

The third example fails because Python isn't C. You get a `SyntaxError` because it's not valid Python code.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I correct in thinking this?

No. The parenthesis are throwing you off. The two methods are equivalent. This:

```
(int)(float_var)
```

Is the same as this:

```
int(float_var)
```

It's not some special "casting" syntax. It's just parenthesis around a name. [The Python grammar allows this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html):

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
testlist_comp: (test|star_expr) ( comp_for | (',' (test|star_expr))* [','] )
trailer: '(' [arglist] ')' | '[' subscriptlist ']' | '.' NAME
```

The parser returns an equivalent abstract syntax tree for each method:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(int)(float_var)'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='int', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='float_var', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))])"
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('int(float_var)'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='int', ctx=Load()), args=[Name(id='float_var', ctx=Load())], keywords=[]))])"
```

However, the third method is not allowed by the Python grammar. As said above, parenthesis around a name is nothing special. It's translated to a function call either way. So while the parenthesis around `int` are optional, the parenthesis at the end are not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between a and b. Saying they are different is like saying `2` and `(2)` are different. The third example fails because a function cannot be called without parenthesis. For example, `int 5` will not work because there are no parenthesis surrounding the parameter.